# Assemble event, methods, property, and values based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assemble an entire function based on data-attributes? I'm trying to assemble a lot of data values. Is there some snippet of code I'm missing or is this considered impossible in withing the javascript language.

```js
$(".div")'.'+$(this).data('event')(function () { 
    $(this).data('window-method')('I was '+$(this).data('event')+'ed'); 
    $(this)'.'+$(this).data('method')($(this).data('property'), $(this).data('value'));
});
// It should say something along these lines
// $(".div").click(function () { 
// alert('I was clicked');
// $(this).css('height', '20');
```

```css
.div  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background: teal;}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-zgND4db0iXaO7v4CLBIYHGoIIudWI5hRMQrPB20j0Qw="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div
  data-event="click"
  data-window-method="alert"
  data-method="css"
  data-property="height"
  data-value="200"
  class="div"></div>
  
  <div
  data-event="dblclick"
  data-window-method="alert"
  data-method="css"
  data-property="width"
  data-value="150"
  class="div"></div>
  
  <div
  data-event="hover"
  data-window-method="alert"
  data-method="css"
  data-property="padding"
  data-value="40"
  class="div"></div>
```

Comment: If it works perfectly fine, then it's probably doable. Why, is another question ?

Comment: It only works if .clicked and alert is put in manually. I want the data attribute to inject those values in automatically.

Comment: Then you should be clearer, and ask a proper question !

Comment: Anyway, it's straight forward -> https://jsfiddle.net/14yuzm62/

Comment: Thanks… I'm new to coding so I don't know all the terms or how to begin to ask coding questions properly.

Comment: No problem, just ask more questions and you'll get the hang of it.